# How to extract certain elements from list of lists?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists:

```
lists=[[1.2,0], [4.5,0], [2.1,1], [6.5,0], [3.4,1]]
```

I want to put all the elements that have 0 together in one list, and all the 1 in another list, so it would look like this:

```
res1=[2.1, 3.4]
res0=[1.2, 4.5, 6.5]
```

I have tried the following, but it does not seem to work:

```
for a in lists:
  for b in lists:
    if b ==0:
    res1.append(lists[1])
    else:
     res2.append(lists[2])
```

I am new to python, and I have tried searching online, but I am unable to find a result. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Python is indent sensitive, so please ensure that is correct. You can simply change the first for loop to `for a, b in lists:` and remove the `for b ...` loop.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The algorithm should be like below:

> for every item in lists
>
> check if the second element of the item is 0 or 1
>
> if 0, append the first element of the item in res0
>
> if 1, append the first element of the item in res1

Let's translate the algorithm in python most simply:

```
lists=[[1.2,0], [4.5,0], [2.1,1], [6.5,0], [3.4,1]]
res0=[]
res1=[]

for i in lists:
     # You have inner lists in i i.e. [1.2,0], [4.5,0] , ... etc  
     if i[1] == 0 :
         res0.append(i[0]) 
     elif i[1] == 1:
         res1.append(i[0])
```

Alternatively, You can do it with simple list comprehension.

```
>>> a = [[1.2,0], [4.5,0], [2.1,1], [6.5,0], [3.4,1]]
>>> [i[0] for i in a if not i[1]]
[1.2, 4.5, 6.5]
>>> [i[0] for i in a if i[1]]
[2.1, 3.4]
>>>
```

BTW, this solution assumes that you have exactly two items in your inner lists.

Comment: Thank you! This makes much more sense now!

Comment: 1.) He didn't, explicitly, specified if 0 or 1 should be in index [1] 2.) Downvoted.

Comment: @AhsanulHaque What my comment means is that he didn't explicitly said that 0 or 1 values could be either on index 0 or index 1 of `lists`. Your solution uses *i[1]* assuming that one of those values will be always on index 1. OTOH, I respect your comments on my answer, so you should respect mines. I'm free to down-vote and comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137517/discussion-between-ahsanul-haque-and-andres-perez-albela-h).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a nested loop for this. Use `a` and `b` as unpacking variables:

```
for a,b in lists:
    if b==0:
        res1.append(a)
    else:
        res2.append(a)
```

Or you could create a new list of lists, with the 0 or 1 serving as the index:

```
result = [[], []]
for a,b in lists:
    result[b].append(a)
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't re-invent the wheel with your own algorithms:

```
my_list = [[1.2,0], [4.5,0], [2.1,1], [6.5,0], [3.4,1]]

with_zero = list(filter(lambda x: 0 in x, my_list))
with_one = list(filter(lambda x: 1 in x, my_list))

print with_zero
print with_one
```

Results:

```
[[1.2, 0], [4.5, 0], [6.5, 0]]
[[2.1, 1], [3.4, 1]]
```

Comment: 1. This is not reinventing the wheel. 2. Filter isn't among the most efficient solutions for this particular problem. 3. This answer doesn't meet OP's requirement. 4. Downvoted.

Comment: `0 in [0.0, 1]` would incorrectly be placed in the `with_zero` category because `in` tests all values not just index `[1]`, similarly `[1.0, 0]` would be put in both lists.